# 64 bit oracle client has been installed,but c# exception saying " with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed."

Tags: c#, oracle, client

running VS C# code to open oracle connection to run a query.. have installed oracle client 64 bit 12c but coudn't open the connection and getting below error.

"Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed."

OS : windows 10 64 bit

VS 2015

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BadImageFormatException. This will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32)

Comment: its 11g.. mine is 12 c

Comment: Did you read an answers??

Comment: It does not make any difference wether you have 11g or 12c

Comment: folder structured for 11g and 12 c are different,so can make changes on basis of 11g

Comment: Are you not able to transform folder name `C:\Oracle\11.2\Client_x86` to folder name where you installed your Oracle?